# How to copy all contents from a worksheet and append these to another sheet (with VBA Access)

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access, export

I have multiple queries and tables, which i am exporting from Access to Excel with:

```
strTablename = "query1"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, strTablename, strFullPath, True, "mastersheet"

strTablename = "query2"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, strTablename, strFullPath, True, "temporarysheet"
'...  and so on
```

After the Export I want to append all the Contents of several Sheets to one mastersheet. And after this I want to delete These Sheets and just want to hold the master sheet with all the Contents of all Sheets, which I add..

Could someone know, how i can solve this Problem? I found no solution in the Forum.

Comment: Why export multiple datasets and not just 1? Solving will require a bunch of VBA. The question is too broad.

Comment: Why not union all the queries and export that one object?

Comment: @Parfait because i have different columns in each query

Comment: Then why append to one worksheet?With empty cols?